# Galliprant & enrofloxacin

Tags: dogs, health, safety, medicines

[image]

Can I give galliprant and enrofloxacin to my 9.8 pound dog. She has a sensitive stomach. I gave her pepcid AC 1hour before enrofloxacin 8:30pm. Its 9:34pm. Is it ok to give her the galliprant. She keeps licking her hind leg a lot so she must be in pain.

The antibiotic is for swollen red paws due to bacteria.

Comment: she looks like a darling dog. I'd check with a vet to be honest. Someone else may know. Let us know how she gets on.